# Accessing existing database's tables with JOIN

Tags: mysql, ruby, join, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an existing database in `MySQL`, that has tables with `many-to-many` relations:

1. `location`
2. `channel`
3. `location_channel` - `JOIN` table.

I have created models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "location"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "channel"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

In rails console I was able to access the records for each table separately, for example: `Location.all` and `Channel.all`,

but when I try to access all `channels` for the given `location` by:

```
location = Location.first
location.channels
```

It's giving error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'mydb.channel_location' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `channel_location`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'switchboard_2_api_poc.channel_location' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `channel_location`
```

Or:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'mydb.channel_location' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `channel_location`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'switchboard_2_api_poc.channel_location' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `channel_location`
```

when I'm trying:

```
channel = Channel.first
channel.locations
```

**I suspect, I need to describe** a `JOIN` table `location_channel` somehow to get rid of the error and print the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell rails the name of the join table,
as it has guessed it wrongly.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :locations, join_table: 'location_channel'
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many